# Default import of static file from public

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am trying to include a css file in my main storybuild during development. Just like we do in normal HTML file, (could be in js way too).

For rest of the packages/components I am using styled components but want to import one at global level too.
I tried in importing webpack but didn't succeed.

Expectation:
The mentioned css file (placed in public) should be available in browser during development.

Edit 1:
Following this repo as boilerplate.
https://github.com/serhii-havrylenko/monorepo-babel-ts-lerna-starter/blob/master/README.MD

Comment: how you are importing your css?

Comment: @adel
For rest of the code it is styled component, i.e component level.
I want one at global level too

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `App.js` or `main.js`

```
    var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';

    if(env === 'dev') {
        import '../path_dev_style.css';
    }
```

Comment: very true, but there IS NO App.js or main.js file present.  

This is done by storybook by default.  

I used the following commnand.
```js

yarn global add @storybook/cli@next
getstorybook
yarn add -DW @types/storybook__react @types/storybook__addon-actions @types/storybook__addon-links react-dom webpack awesome-typescript-loader
```